# how to make ruby on rails database api available for a data driven ios app

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, geolocation

Well , I have just started coding in general. I am trying to make an ios social app with basic picture information taking data from a website ( some what of a flickr-clone)

So , the main website will be built on Ruby on rails.

**EDIT :**

ok so , i want to know when a person uploads a picture , it will have the following entries:
* name
* who took 
* location

I was researching about the gem logtrend (https://github.com/gorsuch/logtrend) , i was wondering if I can make a trending feed of sorts using location?

eg: the user selects a tab which shows them the trending pic ( near them (based on his core location) ?? Can we do something like that ?

Comment: Of course it's achievable, but SO isn't really the place to get opinions on *how* to build such an website.

Comment: any place i can start with it good sir ?

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/ is a great resource for finding popular gems. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ is a great resource for starting to learn Rails.

Comment: You should watch this screencast on using Heroku & Core Data in IOS http://mobile.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Ruby on Rails but I do know to do what you're trying to do (let user upload photos with their name and GPS location to a server, then allow other users to view that photo by downloading it down to their app).

One way you can build the server is to build a web service with Ruby on Rails.

### Web Servcie

The web service (your server) does 2 things:

**1) Accept a Request**

**2) Return a Response**

With the web service, you accept HTTP POST or GET request, then your server's logic code will parse the "parameters" or "variables" inside the POST or GET.

Once your server has these variables, it can save them to the database (an ORM would really make it easier).

Your web service can then return a response using **HTTP Status Code** or a **JSON** formatted response.

### Example Scenario

1) iPhone app takes photo and then makes a HTTP POST request to your Ruby server using **ASIHttpRequest** or **AFNetworking**.

```
// ASIExample
-(void)uploadPhotoToServer
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:myUploadWebServiceURL];

    __block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // setting the POST parameters below
    // note: you will need to get the NSData from a UIImage object
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    [request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
    [request setPostValue:fldName.text forKey:@"name"];
    [request setPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myLatitude] forKey:@"latitude"];
    [request setPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myLongitude] forKey:@"longitude"];

    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];

        if(statusCode == 200)
        {
            [self alertUploadComplete];
        }
    }];

    [request setFailBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Server error: %@", [[request error] localizedDescription]);
        [self alertConnectionProblem];
    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

2) Server receives the request, parses the data and returns a response

```
// Symfony Web Framework example (PHP based web framework)
public function uploadPhotoAction()
{
    // --------------------------------------------------
    // check to make sure all POST parameters are sent 
    // in the POST request by iPhone app.
    // --------------------------------------------------
    if(
        !isset($_REQUEST['name'] 
        || !isset($_REQUEST['latitude']
        || !isset($_REQUEST['longitude']
        || !isset($_REQUEST['photo']
    )
    {
        return new Response($this->sendResponse(406, 'Missing POST parameters');
    }
    else // assumes safe to continue
    {
        /* 
            write code to save the your name, latitude, longitude to your database here 
        */

        /* 
            save your photo to your server's dedicated photo folder, then store
            the file path to the file in your database entry in the above step
        */

        return new Response($this->sendResponse(200, 'Photo uploaded'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of gems that you could make use of are [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) coupled with [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) for social logins/authentication.

For more gems by categories, check out [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/).

Hope you the best of luck!

Comment: wow thanks !! i was going through omni auth . Devise looks great too . thanks a ton !!

Answer (score 0):

*Is this achievable through ruby on rails ?*

Yes, yes it is.

*what gems should I be using ?*

Depends upon your approach and featureset.

*Also , which gems can be used to make API's to feed the IOS app ?*

I think you're misunderstanding what an API is. The API is **HOW** the client will interact with the host.

I would suggest you investigate using JSON to communicate between your IOS app and your Web app. Both IOS and Ruby/Rails are very capable of supporting JSON and it is relatively lightweight.

Also, you need to define, **in detail**, what the IOS application is going to do where it needs interaction with the Web app.

### Example

- IOS App (IA) will save a picture to the Web App (WA).
- IA may save the same picture to WA (overwriting)
- IA will be told if WA is full
- IA will log into WA
- IA can log out from WA
- IA can change password on WA
- WA will reject commands from a non-logged in IA
- IA can retrieve user's pictures from WA
- IA can retrieve any other user's pictures from WA

etc.

Now, for each one, you design the API to support that function.